# Improper configured Google play game services in android game

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-oauth

I have used Google play game services in my android game. But when i download it from test account I get 
"The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account.See logs for more information."
first thing the Google Developers account Owner is not me. I am its "Manger".
So I got to know that only The owner can ask for OAuth 2.0 Client ID. 
I have taken this ID by myself and used in the game. 
Now I deleted this client Id and asked my owner to get one. even after doing this my problem is not yet solved.
One more important point is that I have given SHA1 key for Google Game services debug.keystore rather than release.keystore. 
My game services are already published so it cant be deleted.

Any suggesting or help? What can I do in these circumstances? 
Should I unpublish game? would it then let my owner to recreate Game services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console

Check `Google Developer Console` if the given permission is given correctly for your `Package Name`.

Comment: i have written everything in my question. I wrote that " SHA1 key for Google Game services debug.keystore rather than release.keystore." About package name there is no problem with it. Its just ownership of the account or SHA1 signature.